# position of title and footnote in sas rtf output

Tags: sas, rtf

I wrote a template to create three line tables. It is quite close to what I needed. There are small issues: The title and footnote are separated from the main table by one or two blank lines. How can I change it to eliminate the blank lines between footnotes and the main table? The small for the title line. Thanks in advance.

```
proc template;
    define style tfl_table;
        style body /
            leftmargin = 1in
            rightmargin = 1in
            topmargin = 0.5in
            bottommargin = 0.5in;
        style table /
            frame = hsides
            rules = groups
            cellpadding = 3pt
            cellspacing = 0pt
            width = 100%;
        style header /
            /*This is the header line for the table.*/
            fontfamily = 'Courier New'
            fontsize = 9pt;
        style data /
            /*This is the data in the table.*/
            fontfamily = 'Courier New'
            fontsize = 9pt;
        style SystemTitle /
            fontfamily = 'Courier New'
            color = red
            fontsize = 10pt;
        style systemfooter /
            /*This affects the text in footnoteX statement.*/
            textalign = left
            fontfamily = 'Courier New'
            fontsize = 9pt;
        style NoteContent from Note /
            /*change the font in the compute line*/
            textalign = left
            fontsize = 9pt
            fontfamily = 'Courier New';
    end;
run;

ods html close;
ods rtf file = "&dir.\test-run.rtf" bodytitle style = tfl_table;
ods escapechar = '^';

title1 'First Title with title1 statement';
title2 'Second Title with title2 statement';
footnote1 'footnote1 with footnote1 statement';
footnote2 'footnote2 with footnote2 statement';

proc report data = sashelp.class nowd;
    column sex name age height weight;
    define sex / group;
    break after sex / page;
run;
ods rtf close;

title;
footnote;
```

Comment: If you post this on communities.sas.com Cynthia Zender may have an answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions for fixing the footnote is use the following compute after statement. But I don't know how to eliminate the blank line between title and the main table.

```
compute after _page_;
    line "footnote generated by compute after and line";
endcomp;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you switch it to [`tagsets.rtf`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odsug/61723/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003152286.htm), you'll get rid of one of the footnote blank lines without any other changes (other than removing `bodytitle` which is default in that ODS destination).  I'm not sure if you can remove the one blank line (in part because it's normally a bad thing to remove that line, though of course specific use cases may suggest it).

`tagsets.rtf` also would make it *theoretically* possible for you to make your own modifications - tagsets are editable, in their own language.  Right click on Results, choose Templates, then navigate to SASHELP.TMPLMST.Tagsets.  Look up how to edit tagsets online and how their language works - it's not *that* complicated, but not trivial either.  Feel free to ask questions here, and if anyone knows how to answer them you'll get an answer.